# This cpp code is for loading images using ls command.But it is not loading any image, even though it doesn't show any error.plz help me to fix this

Tags: c++, opencv

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<cv.h>
#include<highgui.h>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
//int count=0;
string getResult(string cmd);

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    IplImage* img;
    int i;
    string ls=getResult("ls -A /home/arya/Images/Input");
    return 0;
}
string getResult(string cmd)
{
    IplImage* img;
    IplImage* imge;
    cvNamedWindow("result");
    string data;
    char buf[128];

    FILE *pipe=popen(cmd.c_str(),"r");
    if(!pipe)
        return "ERROR";

    while(!feof(pipe))
    {
        if(fgets(buf,128,pipe)!=NULL)
            cout<<buf<<endl;
        img=cvLoadImage(buf);
        cvShowImage("result",img);
        cvWaitKey(0);
        cvReleaseImage(&img);
    }
    cvReleaseImage(&img);
    cvDestroyWindow("result");
    pclose(pipe);
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Write the question in the actual question body, not in the title. Also try to narrow the code down as much as possibly yourself first.

Comment: Also indent your code properly, it makes it a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two major problems with your code. The first is that `while (!feof(...))` will not work as you expect it to. That is because the `EOF` flag is not set until *after* you try to read beyond the end of the file for the first time. Instead do e.g. `while (fgets(...) != NULL)`.

The second problem, and the probable cause of your problem, is that `fgets` reads not only the whole line, it also keeps the newline character in the resulting buffer. That means that if you have a line containing the file name `hello.jpg` it will be stored in the buffer as `"hello.jpg\n"`. You need to check for and remove trailing whitespace from the buffer.